# Stack Overflow login system - Is it different from general practice?

Tags: discussion

I have read in many security related articles that **on an incorrect login** to a site the site should not specify whether the username or password is incorrect.

And this is true in practice also. Most sites report invalid login as

`Either username or password incorrect`

**What are the reasons that this type of error message is encouraged?**

If this really is the correct method, then why does Stack Overflow show what exactly is incorrect rather than the general practice?

Comment: If there is another mechanism (typically account registration) which leaks which usernames exist, the security gain of an ambiguous error message disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered by [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) on MSE in an answer on [Is the Stack Overflow login secure against enumeration attacks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132497/is-the-stack-overflow-login-secure-against-enumeration-attacks).

> ... consider that login and recovery attempts are heavily monitored and heavily rate limited by our front-end. It doesn't take more than a few unsuccessful attempts for the system to tell you that it's not accepting any more requests.

To continue on how he would like to see the whole login flow change, not just the message:

> It'd be really nice if the system could say "Are you sure you didn't mean to sign in with your Google / Yahoo / Facebook account?" if we've seen the email before, and then degrade to "email address or password was incorrect" (not hinting at which) if in fact we're certain they're trying to use an SE OpenID.

Do note that after you asked this question (and the after the answer from Tim) the complete Login and Authentication flow was overhauled. See [Stage 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246689/new-year-new-experiment-login-and-signup-ui) and [Stage 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-and-the-new-ui-now-live). The implementation proposal from Tim doesn't seem to have made it into the new design though.

There is a rather similar question with great answers over on [Security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40694/disclose-to-user-if-account-exists) that is worth a read as well the [User eXperience view on the matter](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13516/how-to-tell-the-user-his-login-credentials-are-incorrect)